# Email not being searched properly in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, opensearch

hello I am new to elasticsearch I am having an issue with email search is not working properly I am using boto3 SDK  and AWS opensearch service have tried this mapping

```json
{
  "dev_auth0_logs_new_mapping": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "activity_date": { "type": "date" },
        "activity_type": { "type": "text" },
        "client_id": { "type": "text" },
        "description": { "type": "text" },
        "event_data": { "type": "object", "enabled": false },
        "user_email": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword" } }
        },
        "user_id": { "type": "text" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is my query

```json
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": "10",
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "_source": [
    "user_email",
    "user_id",
    "activity_date",
    "activity_type",
    "description",
    "client_id",
    "id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*ashutosh.pandya@domain.com*",
            "default_field": "user_email",
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [{ "activity_date": "desc" }]
}
```

it is not working with exact match
eg:-ashutosh.pandya it is returning results but for ashutosh.pandya@domain.com it is not returning results
i have followed this blog also [medium  blog](https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/searching-email-address-in-elasticsearch-3b09a11e3c2b) and created new  mapping with custom email analyzer it did not work for me i dont know what i am doing wrong

I have tried this query to get all the logs from ashutosh.pandya@domain.com but did not get any hits

```
{
    "from":0,
    "size":"10",
    "track_total_hits":True,
    "_source":[
       "user_email",
       "user_id",
       "activity_date",
       "activity_type",
       "description",
       "client_id",
       "id"
    ],
    "query":{
       "bool":{
          "must":[
             {
                "query_string":{
                   "query":"*ashutosh.pandya@domain.com*",
                   "default_field":"user_email",
                   "default_operator":"OR"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    },
    "sort":[
       {
          "activity_date":"desc"
       }
    ]
 }
```

but when i search this query

```
{
    "from":0,
    "size":"10",
    "track_total_hits":True,
    "_source":[
       "user_email",
       "user_id",
       "activity_date",
       "activity_type",
       "description",
       "client_id",
       "id"
    ],
    "query":{
       "bool":{
          "must":[
             {
                "query_string":{
                   "query":"*ashutosh.pandya*",
                   "default_field":"user_email",
                   "default_operator":"OR"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    },
    "sort":[
       {
          "activity_date":"desc"
       }
    ]
 }
```

i got all the hits in which user_email contains ashutosh.pandya
I want this :-
if I search ashutosh i got all the hits where user emali contain ashutosh
if I search ashu i got all the hits where user email contain ashu
if I search for pandya i got all the hits where user email contains pandya
if I search  ashutosh.pandya@domain.com i got all the hits where user email equal to ashutosh.pandya@domain.com
if i search for domain i got all the hits where user email contains domain

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom analyzer for wildcard matches. You don't really need your email to be split into tokens at all so use `keyword` type for `email` in the mapping or use `email.keyword` when searching.

Comment: i have tried this it didn't work for me {'from': 0, 'size': '10', 'track_total_hits': True, '_source': ['user_email', 'user_id', 'activity_date', 'activity_type', 'description', 'client_id', 'id'], 'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'query_string': {'query': '*ashutosh.pandya@domain.com*', 'default_field': 'user_email.keyword', 'default_operator': 'OR'}}]}}, 'sort': [{'activity_date': 'desc'}]}

Comment: So it doesn't return anything? Have you tried exact match without wildcards as well?

Comment: like in my case i have to search for all the cases like I want results on wildcards as well as exact match results also that's why i am not using exact match

Comment: It would help to understand the issue. Try `query_string` and `term` queries with exact match.

Comment: I am already using query_string   and I also try with term query its works only for exact match  i have solved this issue by  pattern capture token filte

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this issue by creating a pattern capture token filter
this is the document link [elasticsearch pattern capture token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html)